# printing an email attachment on apple computer in pdf preview help

Tags: pdf, preview, printing

i opened a file attachment and am trying to print from an apple computer. it's in pdf preview. it's looks huge on the screen but tabs and all are inline. but when i click print and it shows a preview of what is about to be printed, it's completely skewed to the right and extremely large. And this is exactly what prints out. help??? how can i make this attachment print correctly.

Answer (score 1):

In the preview there is a button called Actual size.

[image: preview actual size]

That will show you the actual size, and it might be very large pending the file.

In the Preview print menu, you can check the Scale to Fit, and it will fit to your paper size section above.

[image]